# Como obtener una imagen desde un api rest usando HttpClient en angular 4

Tags: typescript, angular, http, blob

Tengo el siguiente servicio en mi aplicación de angular:

```
getProviderPhoto(id:string){
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl+"/"+id+"/images", {responseType: "blob"});
  }
```

Y necesito convertir la respuesta de este servicio, que en este caso es un Blob, a un archivo png para mostrarlo en mi componente HTML.

Esto lo intento hacer a través del siguiente método:

```
 createImageFromBlob(image: Blob) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    this.photo = new File([image],"foto.png",{ type: 'image/png' });
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.photo);
    reader.onload = (event: any) => {
      this.image=event.target.result;
      console.log(this.image);
    }
 }
```

Al llamar este servicio se puede ver en la consola la representación en base 64 de la imagen obtenida:

```
data:image/png;base64,ImlWQk9Sd.....N caracteres.
```

Esta es la parte donde llamo a mi servicio:

```
this.providerService.getProviderPhoto(this.email).subscribe(profilePhoto=>
        {
          this.createImageFromBlob(profilePhoto);
        });
```

Esta es la parte de mi componente HTML donde se muestra la imagen

```
<div class="profile-image center" [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + image + ')'}"></div>
```

*image* es un atributo local que tengo en mi componente donde guardo la imagen.En resumen lo que hace este componente simplemente es hacer una solicitud get a mi api para obtener la imagen de perfil de un usuario y mostarla. Pero el problema es que no funciona.... Entonces como puedo hacer para obtener una imagen desde un api rest y mostarla en mi HTML?